tiny blackberries never grew
We transplanted a 2-year old blackberry plant to a new spot in our public garden.  We didn't expect much in the way of fruit so were surprised to find tiny fruits in late summer-- each about 1/4 inch in diameter.  They never grew, and only part of the plant produced anything.  We had augmented the soil, but didn't test it or anything.  Is this common for a transplant or is there something else we were supposed to do?

How did you 'augment' the soil?

Be patient - blackberries are tough, forgiving plants that are relatively easy to grow. Make sure they aren't being choked at the base by grass and weeds. Don't forget to cut the fruited canes back to ground level each winter. More info here.
